# Merging multiple existence of nodes in under one parent node using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter, xmldom

I have an XML having multiple `<Page Pageid="1">` nodes. All such nodes have `<Para Paraid="1">` nodes under them. I want to do make single occurence of `<Page>` node such that all `<Para>` nodes belonging to same `<Page>` node are shown as child of particular page. e.g.

INPUT:

```
<Page PageID="**1**">
   <Para ParaID="1">
     <some nodes as child of para>
   </Para>
</Page>
<Page PageID="**2**">
   <Para ParaID="**1**">
     <some nodes as child of para>
   </Para>
</Page>
<Page PageID="**1**"> <!Page 1 encountered again>
   <Para ParaID="**1**">
     <some nodes as child of para>
   </Para>
</Page>
<Page PageID="**3**">
   <Para ParaID="**1**">
     <some nodes as child of para>
   </Para>
</Page>
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
<Page PageID="**1**">
   <Para ParaID="**1**">
     <some nodes as child of para>
   </Para>
   <Para ParaID="**2**">           <!all <Para> of Page 1 are under single <Page> node>
     <some nodes as child of para>
   </Para>
</Page>
<Page PageID="**2**">
   <Para ParaID="**1**">
     <some nodes as child of para>
   </Para>
</Page>
<Page PageID="**3**">
   <Para ParaID="**1**">
     <some nodes as child of para>
   </Para>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks to Daniel for updating my Question!

Comment: Do you intend to change `ParaID`? Or is it a typo in sample?

Comment: Yes, ParaID must increment in sequence under each <Page> tag, i.e, first <Para> under each <page> would have ParaID=1, second <Para> would have ParaID=2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5, you can use the XDocument family and Linq extensions to make fairly light work of the task:

```
var doc1 = XDocument.Parse(stringContainingYourXML);
var groups = doc1.Root.Elements().ToLookup(elt => elt.Attribute("PageID").Value);
var unique = groups.AsEnumerable().Select(group => group.First());
var doc2 = new XDocument(new XElement("root", unique));
```

The explanation of this is that we are creating a lookup table on line 2, where elements containing the same value for `PageID` are grouped together. Given your example XML, it takes 4 `<Page/>` elements and creates 3 groups, with one group containing both `PageID="1"` elements.

On line 3, we loop through the 3 groups and extract just the first XML element for one, and on line 4 we jam those 3 elements into a new document. The resulting XML is:

```
<root>
  <Page PageID="**1**">
    <Para ParaID="1" />
  </Page>
  <Page PageID="**2**">
    <Para ParaID="**1**" />
  </Page>
  <Page PageID="**3**">
    <Para ParaID="**1**" />
  </Page>
</root>
```

## Update: 2011/03/12

The code below takes into account the requirement for paragraphs from duplicate instances of a page to be merged together in an auto-incrementing kind of way.

The revised solution is pretty awful compared to the previous one, but messing around with the ParaID values (especially in the format they are in) was quite annoying. I'm not proud of this, but here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SO {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var doc1 = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
            var groups = doc1.Root.Elements().ToLookup(page => page.Attribute("PageID").Value);
            var doc2 = new XDocument(new XElement("root"));

            foreach (var group in groups) {
                var firstpage = group.First();
                var startindex = firstpage.Elements("Para").Last().Attribute("ParaID").Value;
                var lastindex = int.Parse(Regex.Match(startindex, @"\d+").Value);

                // Duplicate pages...
                firstpage.Add(
                    group.Skip(1)
                         .SelectMany(page => page.Elements("Para"))
                         .Select(
                             para => {
                                 para.Attribute("ParaID").Value = Regex.Replace(
                                     para.Attribute("ParaID").Value,
                                     @"\d+",
                                     m => (++lastindex).ToString()
                                 );
                                 return para;
                             }
                         )
                );

                doc2.Root.Add(firstpage);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(doc2);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But here we miss out the 2nd Para of 1st page as available in inupt.

Comment: I think your question must have been edited after I posted my answer. I'm pretty sure the sample output didn't include that. I will start modifying my answer though.

Comment: Also, are those asterisks (eg, `"**1**"` and `"**2**"`) actually there? If so what possible purpose could they provide?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't especially efficient - there's a faster method that uses `xsl:key` - but it will work in most cases where the source document isn't unreasonably large.  Add the following to the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform):

```
<!-- filter out Page elements that aren't the first occurrence for their PageID -->
<xsl:template match="Page[@PageID = preceding-sibling::Page/@PageID]"/>

<!-- for each distinct page, copy all Page child nodes with the current PageID -->      
<xsl:template match="Page">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Page[@PageID = current()/@PageID]/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that you haven't said what to do in the case that there are attributes on the `Page` elements that you're trying to group together, and the above basically ignores them; it will only copy attributes from the first `Page` element with a given `PageID`.